# Building with MSBuild "ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: Request failed."

Tags: msbuild

I get this error
"ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: Request failed."

> Done executing task "AspNetCompiler"
>   -- FAILED.
>
> Done executing task "CallTarget" -- FAILED.
>
> (default target)  (1) -> (Website
>   target) ->   ASPNETCOMPILER : error
>   ASPRUNTIME: Request failed.

I'm trying to build my project using
 the solution

Example:
MSBUILD \\dev\mysolution.sln

I really don't know what this means or how to fix it. Is there a spot where I can find more information through detailed error logs?

Comment: Have you tried to use `/verbosity:diag` [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) when calling MSBUILD? May be this will give some information.

Comment: It provided nearly the exact same information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a tuff Mother F-er.

What was going on and not being said was the computer I was on didn't trust the assemblies I was using on another computer....We all could have got that from the error right? Anyways, there is a fun little tool called, .NET Framework 2.0 Software Development Kit. Once this kit was installed and downloaded I ran an application called, .NET Framework 2.0 Configuration. In this tool I selected

- Runtime Security Policy <-- 
  Once selected in the right pane I selected

  - "Adjust Zone Security"

    - Once this is selected I choose
    - "Make changes to this computer." Click Next

      - On the next screen click "Local Intranet" and move the trust arrow up to "Full Trust" I did it for Trusted Sites also.

Easy enough right? Now we can all build across the network using MSBuild. Yeahh.